# AngularJS -Controller not being invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting out a project with some simple code, but I'm struggling to wire it up correctly. Here's my module.js code:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(['$stateProvider', function appRouter($stateProvider) {

            $stateProvider

                .state('app', {

                    abstract: true,
                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/app/index.html',
                    controller: 'appController'

                })

                .state('app.home', {

                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/home/index.html',
                    controller: 'homeController'

                })

        }]);

})();
```

So, the code within the appController function (below) should be run, but I'm not getting anything in the console. What am I doing wrong?

app.controller.js:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('appController', appController);

        appController.$inject = [];

        function appController() {
            console.log('appController');    
        }

})();
```

I'm not getting any errors, so I know that my modules have instantiated correctly.

Comment: `controller: 'modules/app/app.controller.js'` should be `controller: 'appController'` if you've linked that controller.js in your app. AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, just changed that but still the same result. I'll update the post.

Comment: `url: ' '` isn't going to make that state a default, and it's abstract, so it won't load unless you are on one of the child routes, `/home`.  you don't seem to be handling the default route `/` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you may be having is that you're not creating what I'll call a "root" `angular.module` definition.

In your module code you put:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')

// omitted for brevity
```

And then in your controller you have:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')

// omitted for brevity
```

I don't remember it exactly, but I think it's treating the second `.module` call like a different or new module.

If you change your module's `.module` call to have `[]` as a second parameter, it should work:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [])

// omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you access the "home" state? Because if you don't you ain't getting anything, since the "app" state (and it's controller) won't be instantiated unless a child state (in this case "home") is accessed (because "app" is abstract).

Could you please show your app/index.html and your home/index.html?

Comment: if you have questions, they should be added as a comment